# Conflict with 3 different RewriteRules in .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using the below in my .htaccess file.

There 3 types of redirects:

1. redirect to directory /admin/index.php
2. redirect to specific .php files e.g. /about
3. redirect to user profile page from /John

All 3 work on my local environment, but on the server only 1 and 3 works.
I'd really appreciate for some to tell me why file redirects of the type /about are not working for me.

Many thanks.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^admin$ /admin/index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^about/?$ /about.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([_A-Z0-9a-z-+\.]+)/?$ /public_profile.php?id=$1 [L]

</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Comment: @Tjone, sorry about my formatting.

Comment: In the code you have `Multiviews` which I think should be `MultiViews` because these kind of options are case sensitive. Could you try that?

Comment: Thanks for that @ScallioXTX. I changed it to '-MultiViews' now, but still no luck. I am still being redirected to the 404 page on the server. :(

Comment: Is this the full .htaccess? If not, could you edit and post the full one please? I really don't see anything wrong with what you've posted (other than the MultiViews thing)

Comment: Yup, it's all the text in .htaccess. Been a frustrating 20 hours for me now. :(

Comment: And you're sure about.php exists, i.e., you have uploaded it? Also, do you have access to Apache's main httpd.conf? If so, you should enable RewriteLog to see what mod_rewrite is doing.

Comment: There aren't any cache refreshes or resets that I need to ensure, do i?

Comment: No, no caches or anything. If you want to make sure that you're not seeing the effect of any cache, fire up another browser.

Comment: Yup, I'm trying to get that written in httpd.conf by the server admin. I'll keep this thread updated on my outcome. Thanks @ScallioXTX :)